# checked exception in C#

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are Exceptions not Checked in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124143/why-are-exceptions-not-checked-in-net)

Java makes distinction of "checked exception" and "unchecked exception", does C# have the similiar concepts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C# does not support checked exceptions.  You can read up on why the original design did not include checked exceptions.

Link: [The Trouble with Checked Exceptions](http://www.artima.com/intv/handcuffs.html)

Answer (score 4):

No, there's no such distinction in C#, nor in many other modern languages, even those that run in the JVM (such as Scala).

From the C# Faq, on MSDN: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/why-doesn-t-c-have-checked-exceptions.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Nope, it does not. No. Thankfully!

Answer (score 2):

- [The Trouble With Checked
  Exceptions](http://www.artima.com/intv/handcuffs.html) (Anders Hejlsberg,
  Bruce Eckel, Bill Venners)
- [Does Java Need Checked
  Exceptions](http://www.mindview.net/Etc/Discussions/CheckedExceptions)? (Bruce Eckel)
- [Why doesn't C# have exception
  specifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/vcsharp/team/language/ask/exceptionspecs/default.aspx)? (Anson Horton)

without the CLR itself supporting checked exceptions, it would be effectively impossible for C# to do so alone.

Comment: The last statement is not true, checked exceptions is a type-system feature, not runtime one. It's a Java feature, not JVM feature.