# why does Visual Studio not enforce try-catch-block implementation?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception, try-catch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are Exceptions not Checked in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124143/why-are-exceptions-not-checked-in-net)

Coming from Eclipse/Java, I noticed that in VisualStudio/C# it is not mandatory to care about Exceptions. While Eclipse forces the user to implement a try-catch-block or to add a throws declaration, this is not the case in Visual Studio.

- What is the reason Visual Studio doesn't inform about unhandled exceptions?
- Can I configure Visual Studio to force me to implement try-catch-blocks, or at least add a compiler-warning?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Checked exceptions are not part of .Net, unlike java.

Since the exception does not form a part of the method declaration in c#, any exception can be thrown by any method without the method declaring so. Thus, an exception never requires handling since it is never required to be declared.